# distinguishing between however and though

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions, comparison

I am wondering if a native speaker would apply the two sentences interchangeably, or would detect a difference semantically?

> She wanted to take no risk, however small.
>
> She wanted to take no risk, though small.

Thanks

Comment: There's no need to indicate in your edit that you have updated your question, and it's actually preferred that you don't. There's a revision history where all previous revisions are viewable. I updated your question. Feel free to roll it back if you don't like the changes.

Answer (score 1):

**Meaning**

I definitely feel a difference in meaning.

The first example, with 'however' is fine. The second, however, doesn't work. I actually read "though small" as applying to 'she', so that she doesn't want to take risks, despite the fact that she is small.

To use 'though' to express this thought, I would rephrase like this:

> She wanted to take no risk, though any risk would be small.

or maybe

> She wanted to take no risk, though it be small.

---

**Grammar**

Neither of the two words in question are used as conjunctions in your example sentences.

In

> She wanted to take no risk, however small.

'[However](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/however#Adverb)' is acting as an adverb modifying 'small'. The meaning is "to whatever degree". In other words, no matter how small the risk is, the previous statement still applies.

The other example,

> She wanted to take no risk, though small.

is awkward to the point that I'm not 100% sure it's grammatical. I think '[though](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/though#Adverb)' is acting as an adverb modifying 'small', but I can't say for sure why it seems more natural to me to think that small is modifying 'she' rather than 'risk'.

Usually, after 'though', you would expect a phrase that could be a sentence by itself. You can see this in my example sentences, such as "any risk would be small".